# Bottom right and left page curl that shows shortcuts when swiped?

Tags: applications

My friend and I both have Samsung Galaxy Rugby Pro (SGH-I547) on Android 4.1.2, both fully updated OS and software.

His phone has a bottom right and left page curl effect accessed with a swipe from bottom left or right corners. This will reveal recent apps, swipe again and it reveals favorites, swipe again and it reveals tools.

I can't for the life of me figure out what app or setting makes this happen. I can't even find an image on Google to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. *Omni Swipe* gave me most of the options that I was referring to.

The page curl effect comes with an app called [Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard). It has the option to have the page curl swipe with tools, favorites and recent apps.

Comment: Yes you may accept your own answer, but you will have to wait, my last information was 48 hours.

Comment: I had the same problem, caused by Clean Master as well, as it turned out.

Comment: It is a real shame that android does not let you find out where this weird widget is coming from so that you can disable it

Answer (score 0):

This sounds alot like I tool I have just run across on Google Play. [OmniSwipe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazyswipe), which is a productivity tool that allows for specifying favorites, tools, and settings. If it is not this, it must be something incredibly similar.

From Google Play:

***Omni Swipe*** allows convenient access to your favorite apps, contacts, settings, and incoming notifications using just one hand.

*Just swipe from your screen's bottom left or right corner on any screen to instantly open a customizable radial menu that keeps what's important and most useful to you always within a thumb's reach. Unlike other accessibility tools, **Omni Swipe** stays hidden and out of your way until you swipe it into view to use it.*

I'm not the developer, and I've never used it, but it sounds interesting enough a tool, that I have just installed it! Without this question I may never have been aware of it.

Comment: That is very close to what it was but still doesn't have a page curl option. Thanks for input! Anyone else?